# Read image from database by JQuery (Binary Column)

Tags: javascript, jquery, postgresql

I'm trying to read image from database and show it in my website

when i read the image form postgres database which saved in binary field i got something like that

```
'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
```

I need to show the image and i can't do that while the image is in binary format i think

so how could i convert it and place in my website

Comment: what is your jquery call looks like?

Comment: hmmmm it's complicated that i call python function that get me the data and pass it to jquery

Comment: and how should we help you, if we have no idea, what is going on?

Comment: i think it will not be different if i get the data by JQuery or by python because what i got is the actual data in the database

Comment: your data is binary, that means, at some point python will probably encode it to some other format, then send it to javascript, javascript will probably then try to encode it to something else(string in this case), but I can only guess without knowing the interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Postgres encode() function to convert the binary to base64, then load that in the image tag.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your pictures format, (I'm assuming it's jpeg, use png or etc. ortherwise) use this.

```
var my_source = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(your_binary_string);
```

and put that inside a dom element.

Ex.

```
var my_element = document.getElementById("div_which_image_will_be_located");
var my_image = my_element.createElement("img");
my_image.src = my_source
my_element.appendChild(my_image);
```

Comment: your solution seems fine and yep my image is jpeg ,, but i need a solution that should cover all photos format not only some

Comment: What about saving image formats somewhere on database while taking it? 
Or (worse solution),  `var possible_formats = ['data:image/jpeg;base64', 'data:image/png;base64', ...]; var possibleImageFunction = function(x) {return x+btoa(your_binary_string); }; var possibleImages = possible_formats.map(f=>possibleImageFunction(f));` only one of them will be a valid image. Use all them only the valid one will be visible :)

Comment: Also, please let me know if that solved your problem.

Comment: still searching about it